# Logout when select item in Master detail Side By Side

Tags: oracle-apex

When I select any item on the master records, for some reason the app redirects me to the login page, already tried to recreate the page but didn't work.

I activated the debug in level 9, but it doesn't show me any important info

When I look in the network tab in devtools, its performing a fetch in the login page and its in red

Update: The link looks like this
href="/ords/r/gerencial/gerencial/departamentos-de-para?p18_sa_dim_departamento_padrao_id=1&session=111980260355851&cs=3sYX65TfqbnqSAueW83VCSt4l-x2iIh57g14JVFvI_Tx0sUT9UuWwyi7w7T4-TP_1dzgfpi8DMO70Pb4Rcdq6tg"

Update 2: I noticed that the session in the link is not the current session i have but I don't know how to change the link

Update 3: select v('session') returns the session of the link, not of the current url

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide a [MRE] that allows us to recreate the problem. We cannot see your APP or its code so, at the moment, the question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Oracle apex doesnt have much code that I can show, the problem looks like a bug and I would like to know if anyone is having the same problem

Comment: sounds like the link that you click on is malformed, maybe with a hardcoded session id ? That would cause this behaviour. Can you update the question with an example of the link ?

Comment: I updated the question with the link, it is generated automatically by the page

Comment: that is the actual link, it looks fine but something must be wrong with it that is causing the logout - please post the definition of the link in the application builder. You can also verify yourself: does the session id in the link match your current session ?

Comment: Oh, i checked and it seems to be the problem, but i dont know how master detail generate this link, you have any idea? https://imgur.com/a/tuaj3y1

Answer (score 0):

If enabled, try disabling "friendly url" in your app
[image: Application definition]